# How to get selectedDate using AjaxBehaviorEvent?

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, primefaces

```
<h:outputLabel id="remainingDays" value="#{bean.DueDate}" title="#{bean.remainingDays}"  >
<p:ajax listener="#{bean.listenerMethid}" update="remainingDays,remainingDays" process="remainingDays" event="mouseover"></p:ajax>
</h:outputLabel>
<p:tooltip for="remainingDays" id="tooltip" />



public void listenerMethod(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){


}
```

How can i get Duedate using AjaxBehaviorEvent inside the listenerMethod()

Comment: Since they're in the same bean, this won't be a problem, right? Please explain the situation more and maybe post your relevant part of the bean.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should work as a general way to get the value through AjaxBehaviorEvent:

```
public void listenerMethod(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    String dueDate = (String) ((UIOutput)event.getSource()).getValue();
}
```

However, in your case, you can just access it through the varable (or getter) since it is in the same bean as the listenerMethod.